# Получение записи по id

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, get

Создал не большой ProductList, заполнил таблицу данными, отобразил их на общей страницы. Не могу получить единственную запись по ключу. получаю только первую запись из таблицы, не важно какой бы id= был в ссылке.
http://localhost/ListOPP/bookid.php?id=1 и http://localhost/ListOPP/bookid.php?id=9 отобразить данные первой записи. В процедурном стиле всё получилось, хочу на опп весь ProductList переписать.

Код класса books, и функиции.

```
// database connection and table name
private $conn;
private $table_name = "Books";

// object properties
public $id;
public $scu;
public $img;
public $name;
public $author;
public $description;
public $weight;
public $price;

public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}
function readAll(){

    $query = "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            " . $this->table_name . " ORDER BY
            id DESC";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
function readOne(){

    $query = "SELECT
            *
        FROM " . $this->table_name;

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->id = $row['id'];
    $this->scu = $row['scu'];
    $this->img = $row['img'];
    $this->name = $row['name'];
    $this->author = $row['author'];
    $this->description = $row['description'];
    $this->weight = $row['weight'];
    $this->price = $row['price'];

}
}
```

Также делал такой вот запрос, но почему возвращает только 3 запись из таблицы, не важно какой id в ссылке указан.

```
$query = "SELECT
            *
        FROM " . $this->table_name . "
        WHERE
            id = ?
        LIMIT
            0,1";
```

Так выглядит доступ из общего файла books.php

```
$books = new Books($db);
    $stmt = $books->readAll();
    while ($books = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($books);
        echo "<div data-price='{$price}' class='item'>";
        echo "<a href='bookid.php?id={$id}'><img class='product' 
src='UI/images/{$img}'></a> ";
        echo "<div class='info'>";
```

И код из bookid.php

```
<?php
// get ID of the product to be read
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: missing ID.');

// include database and object files
include_once "UI/header.php";
include_once 'DB/database.php';
include_once 'Objects/books.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare objects
$books = new books($db);

// set ID property of product to be read
$books->id = $id;

// read the details of product to be read
$books->readOne();
```

Comment: в bindparam пропущен третий аргумент, по-умолчанию он PDO::PARAM_STR, хотя чуть ниже написано `Явно заданный тип данных параметра.` http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: и еще в readOne() нет никаких ни return, ни echo.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вот в чем: у вас в запросе ни единого параметра:

```
$query = "SELECT
        *
    FROM " . $this->table_name;
```

Нужно просто сделать так:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name  . " WHERE id=?";
```